# Git pushing to branch on remote repository doesn't work

Tags: git

I have two repositories origin and fork. I cloned origin locally and added fork as a remote repository. I now created a new local branch, e.g.:

```
git checkout master
git branch new
git checkout new
```

I made some changes to new and committed them locally. Now, I want to push my new branch to the fork repository. I tried the following:

```
git push fork new
```

However, this actually pushes to origin. The new branch is created in origin and not in fork. Why?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `git remote show fork`?.

Comment: @KarthikBose Ah, that's the solution! fork was set up with wrong git URL. It also pointed to origin. Problem solved now!

Comment: Anyways, I've updated the same in the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your remote 'fork' is pointing to wrong URL. You can get all information about your remote repo using this command:

`git remote show <remote_name>`

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[push]
    default = current
```

Comment: Mmmh, I thought this just changes the default behaviour when I don't supply any arguments to push? But I'm specifying the remote and branch name I want to push to. So why is that ignored?